# when any of dropdown menus and radio button changes do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here one radio button `class="gender"` and *3 dropdown menus* `class="type","model","acc"` and one button `class="query"`.

How to click query button when any of values of three dropdown menus changes but not change to empty value and the value of radiobutton is query?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.type , .model , .acc').change(function(){
    if($(".type select option[value='selectionKey']").attr('selected') == 'selected' && $(".model select option[value='selectionKey']").attr('selected') == 'selected' && $(".acc select option[value='selectionKey']").attr('selected') == 'selected'&& $('.gender input[type="radio"]').attr("value")=="male"){
      $('.query').click();
      alert('123')
    }else{
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input calss="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input calss="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<br>
<select calss="type">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option1">option2</option>
  <option value="option1">option3</option>
  <option value="option1">option4</option>
  <option value="option1">option5</option>
</select>
<select calss="model">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option1">option2</option>
  <option value="option1">option3</option>
  <option value="option1">option4</option>
  <option value="option1">option5</option>
</select>
<select calss="acc">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option1">option2</option>
  <option value="option1">option3</option>
  <option value="option1">option4</option>
  <option value="option1">option5</option>
</select>
<br>
<input class="query" type="button" value="Query">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to correct your code :

Change `calss` to `class` also for each `class of type,model,account` you have used same `value="option1"` which needs to be changed accordingly as

Change this:

```
<select calss="acc">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option1">option2</option>
  <option value="option1">option3</option>
  <option value="option1">option4</option>
  <option value="option1">option5</option>
</select>
```

To this

```
<select class="acc">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
```

Now answer to your question is :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.type , .model , .acc').change(function(){
        if($(".type :selected").val() != '' || $(".model :selected").val() != '' || $(".acc :selected").val() != ''){
          $('.query').click();
          alert('123')
        }else{
           alert('no option is selected);
        }
      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input calss="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input calss="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<br>
<select calss="type">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
<select calss="model">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
<select calss="acc">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
<br>
<input class="query" type="button" value="Query">
```

Comment: thank you it working , i take options tag copy and forget to edit value :) , but i edit Or (||) to and (&&) , and add one more condition to if : && $('.gender [type="radio"]').attr("value")=="male"){....   thanks,:)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="radio"], select').click(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/25/)

Comment: Unfortunately not suffice. :(

Answer (score 0):

1)You need to use `.is(':selected')` property.

> .is() selector check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

2)If you want to get value from `radio` button you need to use `:checked` property like this:

```
if($('.gender:checked').val()=="male"){}
```

Here is solution :

```js
  $('.type , .model , .acc').change(function(){
    if($(".type option[value='option1']").is(':selected') && $(".model option[value='option2']").is(':selected') && $(".acc option[value='option3']").is(':selected')  && $('.gender:checked').val()=="male"){
      $('.query').click();
      alert('123');
    }else{
    
    }
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<br>
<select class="type">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
<select class="model">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
<select class="acc">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
<br>
<input class="query" type="button" value="Query">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking the selected data value length like this- `if (this.value.length > 0)` and after that, trigger a click on the button :)

Demo code is given here-

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#query').click(function()
    {
        alert("Query Clicked");
    });

    $('input[type=radio][name=gender], select').on('change', function()
    {
        if (this.value.length > 0)
        {
            $('#query')[0].click();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input calss="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input calss="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>

<br>

<select calss="type">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>

<select calss="model">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>

<select calss="acc">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
<br>
<input id="query" type="button" value="Query">
```